# Nighwatchjs reading text file nodejs

Tags: node.js, nightwatch.js

Can anyone help me, i'm trying to add client information on website by reading a text file but i cant get this to work. I want each line to be added

sample text

```
John:Doe:555-555
Jane:Doe:555-555
Ann:Doe:555-555
```

--

```
const fs = require('fs');
module.exports = {

  'Add Client Info': (browser) => {
    fs.readFile('RESERVED-CLIENT.txt', {encoding: "utf8"}, function read(err, data) {
    data.split('\r\n').forEach(i => {
      const a = i.split(':')
      const first_name =  a[0];
      const last_name = a[1];
       const phone_number = a[2];
      return (
        browser
          .url('https://localhost:8000/admin/dashboard')
          .waitForElementVisible('.add-new-client-form', 5000)
          .waitForElementVisible('input[id=client-firstname]', 5000)
          .waitForElementVisible('input[id=client-lastname]', 5000)
          .waitForElementVisible('input[id=client-phone]', 5000)
          .setValue('input[id=client-firstname]', `${first_name}`)
          .setValue('input[id=client-lastname]', `${last_name}`)
           .setValue('input[id=client-phone]', `${phone_number}`)
          .click('#add-client-button')
          .waitForElementVisible('.notice-dashboard', 5000)
           .end()
           )
      })
    })
  }
}
```

i got error `✖ TypeError: Cannot read property 'split' of undefined`

Comment: The solution is easy if you want to use a `json` file instead of a text file.  If you want `json` instead let me know and I'll show you how to do it.

Answer (score 0):

This code is running fine. You can check it online [here](https://repl.it/@mihaifm/invalidFile?language=nodejs), without the nightwatch setup.

The problem is that you are probably reading an invalid file and `data` is undefined when performing the split: `data.split('\r\n')`

You might want to handle the `err` parameter passed to the `fs.readFile` callback, which will give you the error in case the file is missing:

```
const fs = require('fs');
module.exports = {
  'Add Client Info': (browser) => {
    fs.readFile('RESERVED-CLIENT.txt', {encoding: "utf8"}, function read(err, data) {
      if (err) throw err;
      data.split('\n').forEach(i => {
        const a = i.split(':')
        const first_name =  a[0];
        const last_name = a[1];
        const phone_number = a[2];

        // ....

      });
    });
  }
}
```

This displays:

```
Process crashed with: Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'RESERVED-CLIENT.txt'
```

Comment: can you review the answer? @JEEZSUSCRIZE